# "Symmetry of trace" passage in the proof of Chern Weil.

Tags: differential-geometry, trace, characteristic-classes

Related to [this question for the background](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617121/passage-in-the-proof-of-chern-weil-method-in-john-roes-elliptic-operators-book/2617336#2617336).

Let $\Omega$ be the curvature $2$-form if a principal bundle $E$ of frames (associated to a complex vector bundle $V$), let $\omega$ be the matrix valued connection on $E$. Assume that $\omega$ depends on a parameter $t$ (this is a passage for proving that the Chern Weil method doesn't depend on the connection used). By $\omega'$ I will denote the derivative with respect to the time. In the proof there is the following passage: $$ \text{tr}\{\Omega^n(\omega\omega'+\omega'\omega)\}= \text{tr}\{\Omega^n\omega\omega'-\omega \Omega^n\omega'\}$$ justified with the comment **by the symmetry of trace**.

Now it's unclear to me what symmetry we are referring to, I would simply notice that since $\omega$ is a $1$-form and $\Omega$ a $2$-form then $$\Omega^n\omega'\omega =- \omega\Omega^n\omega'$$ since first we swap order of $\omega,\omega'$ introducing a $-1$ in front and then swap order of $\omega,\Omega^n$ which doesn't not introduce any sign change being $\Omega$ a $2$-form.

Is that correct? what is this symmetry mentioned by the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the negative sign, but wrong about the equality: note that both $\omega$ and $\Omega$ are $\mathfrak{gl}_m(\mathbb C)$-valued differential forms. In terms of local coordinates,

$$\omega = \omega_i^j, \ \ \ \Omega = \Omega_i^j.$$

Now write $A = \Omega^n \omega'$, where $A = A_i^j$. Then

$$(\Omega^n \omega' \omega)_i^j = (A\omega)_i^j = A_i^k \omega_k^j,\ \ \ (\omega \Omega^n \omega')_i^j = (\omega A)_i^j = \omega_i^k A_k^j = -A_k^j \omega_i^k.$$

(the -ve sign comes from the fact that both $A, \omega$ have odd degrees). So $\Omega^n \omega' \omega \neq -\omega\Omega^n \omega'$ unless $m=1$. But after taking trace,

$$\operatorname{tr}(\Omega^n \omega' \omega) = \operatorname{tr}(-\omega\Omega^n \omega') =\sum_{i,k} A_k^i \omega_i^k. $$

So by symmetry of trace, it is really the linear algebra fact that if both $A, B$ are square matrices, then $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(BA)$.

Comment: So what I was getting wrong is the fact that since are matrix valued forms one has to be careful about moving the forms. Is that right?

Comment: It's the fact that since they are matrices, they are not commutative in general. @Riccardo

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm quite new to this kind of reasoning so thanks for clarifying the passage!