# Proving that a form is horizontal in the Chern Weil method proof

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, characteristic-classes, principal-bundles

Follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617121/passage-in-the-proof-of-chern-weil-method-in-john-roes-elliptic-operators-book).

$\omega$ is a one parameter family of connections on a principal bundle of frames $E$, associated to a complex vector bundle $V\to M$.

In the proof of the Chern Weil method in John Roe's book, one start with the curvature of a complex vector bundle $V\to M$ and then works in the associated frame bundle $E$. There (i.e. as forms on $E$) he gets the equality: $$\frac{d}{dt}\log \det(1+q\Omega)= d\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(-1)^lq^{l+1}\text{tr}\{\Omega^l \omega'\}$$

The point is that we want to obtain such relation on $M$, in a certain sense we want to push down these forms to forms on $M$. The way to do that, according to the author, is to observe that the form on the LHS is the exterior derivative of an **horizontal and invariant** form on E. Hence since there is a $1-1$ correspondence between horizontal and invariant forms on $E$ and forms on $M$, we are done since we are allowed to push everything down.

Why is the form $$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(-1)^lq^{l+1}\text{tr}\{\Omega^l \omega'\}$$ horizontal and invariant?

According to a proposition in the book, the form $\Omega$ (i.e. the curvature) is horizontal (and $Ad$-equivariant), but $\omega$ is not horizontal at all (by definition), but it's still Ad-equivariant.

Since the trace is an invariant polynomial, it's enough to prove that $\Omega^l\omega'$ is horizontal. Problem is that I don't have much control on $\omega'$. Any suggestion? Does it suffice to have only $\Omega$ invariant?